# this in a global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

the statement:

```
for( var item in this){
    console.log( item );
}
```

Is a noop in the global context. However in a function

```
function foo(){
    for( var item in this){
        console.log( item );
    }
}
foo();
```

This produces the global environment objects. 
What is the reason for this behaviour?

What is the syntax for accessing the objects currently in scope, as in the first sample?

Comment: Yes, just tested it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/Luvbp/ - works as expected.

Comment: I'm running this in node.js. Is this not a language defined quality?

Comment: node is probably the cause...

Comment: Not that `this` has nothing to do with scope. It always references a local parameter in the current execution context, so it's never resolved on the scope chain (i.e. beyond the current context). But  that will change if Brendan Eich gets a lexical `this` in the [harmony of his dreams](https://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/). :-)

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for [binding objects](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2.1.2). But, they aren't typically exposed within the language beyond the [global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1) ([`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) in Node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` is probably pointing to the exports object of node.

So in the first case, the `this` is right not to point at the `window` object. In the second case, well, the `this` is inside a function (which is not a method of an object) so, as you'd expect, it points back to the `window`.

Comment: exports is an object defined in Node?

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo—so how do you access the global object in node.js in a strict mode safe manner? Is there a reason to do so?

Comment: `var global = (function () {return this;})();` - or something like it. I can't see what could go wrong.

Comment: @RobG Using the global keyword. I don't see where's the problem.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas—cool, I guess that's a fairly fundamental thing to learn about Node.js then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, "this" is not the current object but the running context of the current method.

For example :

```
function foo(){ 
   console.log(this);
}
```

In global context :

- if I call *foo()*, the console log *global*
- if I call *setTimeout(foo, 0)*, the console log the Timer object because foo are call by the timer.

The best way to call your method are to use the call method of the Function object to bind yourself the running context when you call your method.

```
foo.call(this);
```

---

*Sorry for my bad english. ^-^*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

In the global scope, `this` refers to the global object.

In strict mode (which you seem not to have enabled) a simple function call leads to a `undefined` this-value.

For non-strict function (like your `foo`) a simple call leads to `this` being the global object again.

Answer (score 1):

[ECMA-262 §10.4.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1.1) shows that when entering a global execution context, `this` is set to the global object. So if the first code example is executed in a global context, `this` should reference the global object.

I don't have `node.js`, but if that is the host environment you should add a `node.js` tag to the question to attract someone who knows about `node.js`.

In the second example, the function's `this` is not set by the call, so it defaults to the global object. In strict mode, it will be undefined and attempting to access `this` will throw an error.

Comment: It seems that the node.js globals object muddled my thinking.